# API-Platform 2.6 when doing GET request with UUID it convert to binary in the Doctrine Query

Tags: symfony, api-platform.com

I am using API-Platform 2.6 and I have an entity declared like this:

```
namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: MyEntityRepository::class)]
class MyEntity {

    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\Column(type: 'uuid', unique: true)]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy: 'CUSTOM')]
    #[ORM\CustomIdGenerator(class: 'doctrine.uuid_generator')]
    private ?Uuid $id = null;

}
```

But when I try to fetch an entity using the UUID from the DB I get a 404 error.

In my DB, the entity table, has the UUID saved normally like that: `24306098-7e56-1ed9-8f48-db0c83a39071`

Then when I try to fetch this using the url: `http://my-local-server/api/my-entity/24306098-7e56-1ed9-8f48-db0c83a39071` I get the 404.

Finally, when I open the profiler, and checking the SQL Query I get this:

[image]

Just to let you know, I've tried lot's of different solutions I found on the internet, but none of them worked for me.

Any idea why I have this error or how can I solve this issue? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Finally found the solution.

The problem wasn't either the Symfony nore the API-Platform.

The issue was the PHP Storm itself. I place my answer here for other developers may using PHP Storm and have the same troubles as me.

When I listed the entity records inside the PHP Storm, the PHP Storm had activated the UUID Column formatter to be "UUID with time-low and time-high swapped" which made the UUIDs looks good but wasn't the original ones need it for the GET Operations in the Rest API.

By mistake I found that I can change the format in the table by using the context menu like that:

[image]

Thank you all for the time you took review my issue.

Comment: Yes this is down side of this field type. I use myself DBeaver and there is also an method to render binary as UUID.

To create new UUID on the server i use mostly the following command UUID_TO_BIN(UUID()) that helped me really much